# Common obstacles to reaching a negotiated or mediated divorce settlement?

Tags: divorce, mediation

I am trying to understand, in general, the common obstacles to reaching a negotiated or mediated divorce settlement and ways to avoid or deal with those obstacles.  Any thoughts or resources to suggest?

Comment: Apart from money, children, and Congreve's law: "Heaven hath no wrath like love to hatred turn'd". Since you've not specified where this divorce is occurring, I'm guessing you want generalities; so the biggest obstacle is always going to be that one or both parties simply refuse to be reasonable because they want to hurt the other.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins  How do negotiators try to deal with such motivations?  Since such motivations are common yet very few divorces actually go to court, there must be ways to overcome the obstacles.

Comment: You say very few go to court - in what country? Because that might be down to individual laws regarding divorce or even prenuptial arrangements.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins   In the USA, the vast majority of divorce proceedings do not result in an actual trial.  The divorce may be filed in court and there may be preparations for trial, but relatively few cases actually go to trial, or so I have read.

Comment: In the US, it's usually the lawyers doing the negotiating and they will be professional, including teaching their client what they can and can't expect. They'll often act as intermediaries, keeping belligerent couples apart thought the process.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I am seeking some insight into the details of the process, beyond lawyers being professional.

Answer (score 1):

#### Obstacle #1: Emotion

Family law issues are wrought with emotion. This clouds judgment and reasoning capacity. This is the biggest obstacle in my experience.

#### Obstacle #2: Punishment motive

Related to obstacle #1, this is a very specific desire of one party to "punish" the other for perceived past wrongs.

#### Obstacle #3: Lack of prioritizing children's interests

Many issues can be resolved if both parties take an objective look at what's in the best interest of the children and act accordingly. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen all too often.

#### Recommendations

My recommendations to you are as follows.

1. Both parties should hire an attorney.
2. The parties should jointly hire a ***professional mediator*** who has a long track record and specializes in mediating family law matters.
3. Leave the emotions out of it and look out for the best interests of the children first.
4. Be wary of attorneys who seek to push emotional hot button issues.

Comment: What are some of the tools or techniques that professional mediators use to help move the parties toward settlement?

Comment: @user3270: In my opinion, this is one of the best things about the legal system... mediators. Especially in family law where emotions reign. What happens is, each party and his/her attorney sits isolated in one room while the other party and their attorney sits in a separate room. The parties never see or talk directly to each other but only through the mediator who bounces between rooms. The parties engage in a series of proposals and counter proposals until an agreement is struck. The mediator has lots of influence to pull the parties together with "helpful suggestions." It works!

Comment: @user3270: The mediator's leverage over the parties on points of contention is... "if this goes to trial, the judge could rule against you because of X, Y and Z." He puts the fear of being ruled against into the calculation of both parties. This helps move the parties together. Toward the middle ground. Both parties have to believe the mediator is as objective as the judge would be and, accordingly, view him as a judge proxy. This is easy to go if the mediator is experienced and has a good reputation and spotless track record.

Comment: @mowzer as a professional mediator I would never conduct a mediation where the parties were not in the same room with me. Also lawyers can be there to advise and support their clients but not to take part in the mediation process. This is *their* mediation, not mine or anyone else's - if they are unwilling to participate on those terms then I will wish them good luck in court.

Comment: @DaleM: Just to be clear. In the scenario I describe, one party is always in the same room as ***you*** (except for your time in transit). However, they are ***never*** in the same room as ***each other!*** Your comment doesn't make it clear you understood that. Do you still disagree that's the best way to go? Because if you do, please read the following comment.

Comment: @DaleM: If you haven't tried separating the parties, I think you are missing an opportunity to potentially serve your clients with a better product and be a more effective mediator. So, "you're welcome" (for this new idea to try). I have participated as a party in both kinds so I can speak from experience having done both. The one where the parties are separated is MUCH more effective. It helps to keep the emotions in check when the parties can't see each other or communicate directly. It also gives the mediator more influence over the parties to help them reach a negotiated settlement.

Comment: @DaleM: Also, when you say, *"if they are unwilling to participate on those terms then I will wish them good luck in court."* Please keep in mind that court isn't their only other option. They can just hire a different mediator.

Comment: @Mowzer What you are describing sounds like conciliation, not mediation. A good mediator has plenty of influence over the parties but ultimately they have to be able to talk to one another directly if they are going to take ownership of the outcome. Conciliation is a similar but different ADR technique. A conciliator can propose and encourage solutions, a mediator should never do that.

Answer (score -2):

As someone who has been through that mill...adopt a philosophy of the "shoe on the other foot."

Look objectively at what your "ask" is, and think about if that is something you would readily concede to the other side.  If it is, bravo, and good luck, hold your head high and give it a shot.

Answer (score -4):

If both parties honor their marriage vows, there will not be a divorce.

If either party honors their marriage vows, the divorce attorneys will have a hard time "reaching a negotiated or mediated divorce settlement".

[Mark 19:7-12](http://biblehub.com/kjv/mark/10.htm).